# Run query against all databases on server containing specific string in name

Tags: sql-server, query

If I have a query such as:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, DateTime, 100) AS "Date and Time"
,Text2 AS Area
,Substring(PText7, 1,Charindex(':', PText7)-1) AS Username
FROM the_database.dbo.AlgViewENU AS data
WHERE PText6 LIKE '%BypIn%' AND DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM the_database.dbo.AlgViewENU WHERE Text1 = data.Text1 AND PText6 LIKE 'Set%')
```

How would I run the same query against all the databases in the server containing "the" (for example) in the name? I haven't had any luck with ***sp_MSforeachdb***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to generate a dynamic statement.

Basic example:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @err int
SET @stm = N''

-- Dymanic statement
SELECT @stm = @stm + CONCAT(N'SELECT * FROM [', [name] , N'].sys.tables ')
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] LIKE '%the%'

-- Execution
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
```

Example with your statement:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @err int
SET @stm = N''

-- Dymanic statement
SELECT @stm = 
    @stm + 
    CONCAT(
    N'SELECT convert(varchar, DateTime, 100) AS "Date and Time", Text2 AS Area, Substring(PText7, 1,Charindex('':'', PText7)-1) AS Username FROM [', 
    [name] , 
    N'].dbo.AlgViewENU AS data
    WHERE PText6 LIKE ''%BypIn%'' AND [DateTime] = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM [',
    [name] , 
    N'].dbo.AlgViewENU WHERE Text1 = data.Text1 AND PText6 LIKE ''Set%''); '
    )
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] LIKE '%the%'

-- Execution
PRINT @stm
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it using `sp_MSForeachdb`, maybe my first example will help you to understand how to do it.

This code select all the databases containing "the"in the name:

```
exec sp_MSForeachdb    'if ''?'' like ''the%''  SELECT ''?'''
```

This code should do what you requested:

```
exec sp_MSForeachdb
'if ''?'' like ''the%''
SELECT convert(varchar, DateTime, 100) AS [Date and Time]
,Text2 AS Area
,Substring(PText7, 1,Charindex('':'', PText7)-1) AS Username
FROM ?.dbo.AlgViewENU AS data
WHERE PText6 LIKE ''%BypIn%'' AND DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM the_database.dbo.AlgViewENU WHERE Text1 = data.Text1 AND PText6 LIKE ''Set%'')'
```